# Strange margin in a resized img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Conisder the html code below:

```html
<a>
<img src="//path/to/img.jpg" />
</a>
```

The CSS code is

```css
a {
   height: 64px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
   display: block;
}

img {
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

The original size of the image is 246 x 74. Due to the effect of css codes, the height of image will be resized into 64 - 10 * 2 = 44px. The aspect ratio of the image will remain unchanged, which means the width of the image will becoem 44 / 74 * 246 = 146px. The browser renders the image tag as expected. However, the width of the `a` tag is 246px instead of 146px;

[image]

[image]

As shown in the figure, there is a strange "brown block" to the left of the `img` tag, which is not listed as margin.

My question is how can I make the width of the `a` tag equal to the width of the `img` tag without explicity set `width: 246px` for the `a` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `width: max-content`

Comment: Thanks~, the width of the `a` tag is now correctly rendered. However I notice that the "strange brown block" now moves to the `a` tag.  Which mean the parent of `a` tag will have the similar problem. Is there a way to elimate this strange brown block?

Comment: if you are talking about the margin you can remove it from all elements and then add them to the elements you want by adding
```* {margin: 0;}```
```*``` is the universal selector

Comment: That "brown block" is not listed as a margin in chrome. I try to add "* {margin: 0}" and it does not work.

Comment: what is style of a tag parent?

Comment: @WoodyHuang Can you add a screen shot or if the brown block is the one in the screenshot with the question so it is margin but if it is something else so let me see

Or it is just because of the alignment like if it is in left then there may be a block at the right and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a {
  height: 64px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-diffie-9o9mc?file=/src/styles.css)